# Issue with compatability / jquery calling function twice?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps, toggle

I am running two different things on my wordpress site, one is a jquery toggle on a page and the other is a google maps api on a different page.

When I have the following version of jquery in the header, my toggle works, but the google map function doesn't.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then when I put either one of the newer versions of jquery below in the header, the opposite happens, the map works but then the toggle doesn't.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use multiple versions of jQuery in a page.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with Google Maps, Actually Google Maps need to be called first and separately,  google maps load itself and after that it doesn't allow any other script to get executed and if you try to call Google map from some other function then it will not work as I already told you that it need to be called at Document.ready function. Use two different document.ready function that might help you.

And one more thing, use $.noConflict() at starting of document.ready.